# Row extraction from matrix in comparison to a smaller sized array.

Tags: matlab, matrix, weekday

I have a array "HolidayArrayDate" of 10 x 1 in decimal days.

```
734870
734884
```

so on

I have a matrix "weekdayRows" of 260 x 5 in decimal days

```
734870 734870.2 734870.4 734870.6 734870.8
734871 734871.2 734871.4 734871.6 734871.8
```

so on.

I have a matrix of "weekendRows" of 104 x 5 in decimal days

```
734870 734870.2 734870.4 734870.6 734870.8
734871 734871.2 734871.4 734871.6 734871.8
```

so on

How do i remove the 10 days in holidayArrayDate from weekdayRows and add them to weekendRows?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly

```
index=ismember(weekdayRows(:,1),HolidayArrayDate);
Temp=weekdayRows(index,:);
% to remove them from weekdayRows 
weekdayRows(index,:)=[];
% to add to weekendRows
weekendRows=[weekendRows; Temp];
% you might need to sort if the ordering is important
weekendRows=sort(weekendRows,1);
```